# Using AWS IoT's ThingShadow with a Websocket Connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

When I first started learning how to use aws, I connected my device/thingShadow to the IoT core by going to the AWS IoT management console and creating "Things." Each thing came with a private, public, and certificate keys that you would use to connect to IoT by doing the following:

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

const keyPath = `./260b380cc2-private.pem.key`
const certPath = `./260b380cc2-certificate.pem.crt`
const caPath = './rootCA.pem'
const clientId = 'client'
const host = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'

var thingShadow = awsIot.thingShadow({
    keyPath: keyPath,
   certPath: certPath,
     caPath: caPath,
   clientId: clientId,
       host: host
 });

 var shadowName = 'testShadow'
 
 thingShadow.on("connect", () => {
    thingShadow.register(shadowName, {}, () => {

        console.log("Conneced. Getting shadow")        
        thingShadow.get(shadowName)
    })
})

thingShadow.on('status',
    function(thingName, stat, clientToken, stateObject) {

       console.log('received '+stat+' on '+thingName+': '+
                   JSON.stringify(stateObject))})
```

Now, instead of connecting to the IoT Core using the RSA keys, I'm connecting a device through a websocket protocol using Amazon's Cognito identity pool:

```
Aws = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');
awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

const AWS_REGION = 'us-east-2';
const AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL = 'us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com';

Aws.config.region = AWS_REGION
Aws.config.credentials = new Aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL
})

Aws.config.credentials.get(() => {
    const config = {}
    let client
    
    config.host = AWS_IOT_ENDPOINT
    config.protocol = 'wss'
    config.clientId = `client-${Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1)}`
    config.accessKeyId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    config.secretKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    
    //client = awsIot.device(config)
    client = awsIot.thingShadow(config);
    
    client.on('connect', (success) => {
        if (success) {
            console.log("Connected.")
            client.register('testShadow')
            client.get('testShadow')

        } else {
            console.log("Could not connect.")
        }
       
    })

    client.on('close', () => {
        console.log("Connection closed.")
    })
    
    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        console.log(topic, message)
    })

    client.on("status", (shadow, stat, id, state) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state))
    })
    
    client.on('error', error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
})
```

The problem with the second code block is that when I use `client = awsIoT.thingShadow(config)`, the client fails to connect and prints `Could not connect.` But when I use `client = awsIot.device(config)`, the client connects and prints out `Connected` (when I used `aws.Iot.device`, I don't include the `client.register` and `client.get` code lines). Other than that, I don't get any errors of any kind, so I'm not sure why it's failing to connect or what I should be doing so that I can get a thingShadow to connect through a cognito identity pool. Is it even possible? If it is, how can I get that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Do your AWS IAM credentials that you use in the WS example have the needed [permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policy-actions.html) to access the device shadow?

Comment: When creating the pool, there's 2 IAM Roles. One for authenticated identities and one for unauthenticated identities. The unauthenticated identity didn't seem to have a policy to edit, but the authenticated identity did. I modified that identity to include: connect, publish,  receive, subscribe, getThingShadow, and updateThingShadow. I've seen online about people needing to attach two policy's, or something along those lines. In addition, I'm not sure if the client is connecting as an authenticated identity or as an unauthenticated one.

Comment: You can enable [logging in the AWS IoT Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/configure-logging.html#configure-logging-console), this will tell you the reason why authentication attempts fail.

Comment: also, [aws-sdk-react-native](https://github.com/amazon-archives/aws-sdk-react-native) seems to be deprecated in favor of [Amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/). AWS IoT Access is built into Amplify: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js#aws-iot